# Real value output from classifiers

Tags: machine-learning

I am currently trying to implement a machine learning system that is capable of looking at a training data set and is capable of producing a real valued output between 0 to 100 based on the inputs.

Currently I am using a linear regression model to determine the output. However, I have reached a wall when it comes to thinking of other classifiers that can be an alternative to the the regression model. The basic need is that the output of the classifiers should be a real value between 0 to 100. I have tried looking at neural networks and decision trees however, I am not able to wrap my head around the way to go about it. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Dataset**

I am extracting 4 different features from the dataset. All the features are real values themselves. I have 185 different files from each I can extract the 4 features.So in the end I end up with a matrix of 185 rows and 4 columns.

Comment: Do you want to write the code yourself?

Comment: Most classification methods have a regression counter-part (neural networks, Gaussian processes, decision trees, SVM) it's really just about how you generate the output (binary or continuous) . [This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_tree_regression.html) is an example pulled from the excellent scikit-learn library, there are many more regression examples on this site.

Comment: Logistic regression may be an option. That predicts values in the range (0,1), which can of course be scaled to other ranges.

Comment: @larsmans      I shall have a look at logistic regression as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An artificial neural network (ANN) with sigmoid activation will output values in the range (0,1) so you would only need to scale the outputs to the desired range (in your case, just multiply the output by 100).

Since you have 4 features, you would create an ANN with 4 units (neurons) in the input layer and a single unit in the output layer. The decision you need to make is how many hidden layers and how many units in each hidden layer. Without knowing more about the nature of your problem, I recommend starting with no more than two hidden layers (starting with one is probably better) and putting about 6 or 8 units in the hidden layer.

Comment: Thanking you for pointing me in the right direction. I am looking for doing the same myself.But I shall take you advice and start with a single hidden layer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want. Rulequest's [cubist](http://www.rulequest.com/cubist-info.html) will output real value for you, but you will need to set up files correctly. There are many neural network libraries out there too.